# Django: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'auth.User' that has not been installed

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy a Django app to **Heroku**. It works on my localhost but I get this error when deploying to heroku:

```
File "./blog/models.py", line 6, in <module>
2021-03-24T23:31:05.696194+00:00 app[web.1]: User = get_user_model()
2021-03-24T23:31:05.696219+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 162, in get_user_model
2021-03-24T23:31:05.696372+00:00 app[web.1]: "AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
2021-03-24T23:31:05.696397+00:00 app[web.1]: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'auth.User' that has not been installed
```

I have tried setting `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'` in settings after doing `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` and:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

but nothing works.

**settings.py**

```
import django
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
# from django.contrib.auth.models import User #todo: this causes ImproperlyConfigured: SECRET_KEY MUST NOT BE EMPTY

import os
import django_heroku

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'django_project.settings'
SECRET_KEY = 'asdaf123$9pv98=e6p^gl(-eoj' #todo: test removing this in own deployment

DEBUG = 'True'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig', #allows Django to correctly search your templates for the 'blog' app
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'chat',
    'crispy_forms',
    'channels',
    'dal',
    'dal_select2',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'storages'
]




# ~~~MESSAGES CONFIG~~~
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.asgi.application' # older version of django: 'django_project.routing.application'

# Channels redis config:
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            #"hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)], or 'redis' #l ocal
            "hosts": ['rediss://:p628bf20dab326cedb30d4df129e9691dbb6e7e1f4486954eadbfdf77db854369@ec2-34-235-242-69.compute-1.amazonaws.com:25180'], # REDIS_TLS_URL #todo: confirm. Changed from "127.0.0.1" to 'redis'... found promising answer, changing this
            # 'redis://:p628bf20dab326cedb30d4df129e9691dbb6e7e1f4486954eadbfdf77db854369@ec2-34-235-242-69.compute-1.amazonaws.com:25179' REDIS_URL
        },
        # "ROUTING": "chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns", #todo: add "ROUTING": "chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns",
    },
}

CACHES = {
    "default": {
         "BACKEND": "redis_cache.RedisCache",
         "LOCATION": os.environ.get('REDIS_TLS_URL'),
         "OPTIONS": {
            "CONNECTION_POOL_KWARGS": {
                "ssl_cert_reqs": False
            }
        }
    }
}


DATABASES = { # Use this to use local test DB
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

DB_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
DATABASE_URL = DB_URL


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

django_heroku.settings(locals())

DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = 4000
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfilescustom') #todo: may have to add own staticFileDir folder
]

django.setup()
```

**blog/models (which is where the error is complaining about):**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
from django.conf import settings



from django.urls import reverse
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# we're inheriting from the models.Model
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100) # character field
    content = models.TextField() # Unrestricted text
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()  # Unrestricted text
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=100)  # character field
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    name_and_platform = models.TextField(default='N/A') #todo: find a good max char limit
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name  # return game name when game.objects.all() is called

    def get_name_and_platform(self):
        return ''.join([self.name, '(', self.platform, ')'])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name_and_platform = self.get_name_and_platform()
        super(Game, self).save(*args, **kwargs)




class Trade(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField() # Unrestricted text
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_trade_proposed = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
    user_who_posted = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owned_game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owned_game', db_column='owned_game')
    desired_game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='desired_game', db_column='desired_game')

    def get_trade_name(self):
        return ''.join([self.user_who_posted.username, '(', timezone.now().strftime("%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S UTC"), ')'])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = self.get_trade_name()
        super(Trade, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name # return game name when game.objects.all() is called


class Transaction(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField() # Unrestricted text
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    trade_one = models.ForeignKey(Trade, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='trade_one', db_column='trade_one')
    trade_two = models.ForeignKey(Trade, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='trade_two', db_column='trade_two')
    status = models.TextField()  # Unrestricted text. Validated in form.
    expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.today() + timedelta(days=3))
    open_expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.today() + timedelta(days=9))
    user_cancelled_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def get_transaction_name(self):
        return ''.join([str(self.trade_one_id), ' and ', str(self.trade_two_id), ' on ', timezone.now().strftime("%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S UTC"), ''])

    def get_status_on_insert(self):
        return 'Waiting for 2nd confirmation from ' + str(self.trade_two.user_who_posted)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.name == '':
            self.name  = self.get_transaction_name()
        if self.status == '':
            self.status = self.get_status_on_insert()
        super(Transaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name # return name when game.objects.all() is called

    def get_absolute_url(self): #todo: remove?
        return reverse('confirmed-trade', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**chat/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
# from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone


class Message(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='author_messages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now) #todo: timezone fix?

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author.username

    def last_10_messages(self):
        return Message.objects.order_by('-timestamp').all()[:10] # only load last x msgs from DB
```

**users/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from PIL import Image
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
from django.conf import settings



class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

**chat/consumers.py**

```
# chat/consumers.py
import json
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from .models import Message


from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
from django.conf import settings


class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def fetch_messages(self, data):
        print('~~~fetch_messages~~~')
        messages = Message.last_10_messages(self)
        content = {
            'command': 'messages',
            'messages': self.messages_to_json(messages)
        }
        print('content: ' + str(content))
        self.send_message(content)


    def new_message(self, data):
        print('~~~in new_message: 2~~~')
        author = data['from']
        print('author: ' + author)
        author_user = User.objects.filter(username=author)[0]
        message = Message.objects.create(author=author_user, content=data['message'])
        content = {
            'command': 'new_message',
            'message': self.message_to_json(message)
        }
        return self.send_chat_message(content)


    def messages_to_json(self, messages):
        print('~~~messages_to_json~~~')
        result = []

        for message in messages:
            result.append(self.message_to_json(message))
        return result


    def message_to_json(self, message):
        print('~~~message_to_json~~~')
        return {
            'author': message.author.username,
            'content': message.content,
            'timestamp': str(message.timestamp)
        }

    commands = {
        'fetch_messages': fetch_messages,
        'new_message': new_message
    }


    def connect(self):
        print('~~~connect~~~')
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        # Join room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        print('~~~disconnect~~~')
        # Leave room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    def receive(self, text_data):
        print('~~~receive: 1~~~')
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        self.commands[data['command']](self, data) # either fetch_messages or new_message

    def send_chat_message(self, message):
        print('in send_chat_message: 3')
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)( # Send message to room group
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    def send_message(self, message):
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps(message))

    # Receive message from room group
    def chat_message(self, event):

        message = event['message']
        print('message: ' + str(message))
        content1 = message['message']
        print('content1: ' + str(content1))
        content2 = content1['content']
        print('content2: ' + content2)
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps(message)) # Send message to WebSocket
```

**UPDATE:** When i switched my procfile from

```
release: python manage.py migrate
web: daphne django_project.asgi:application --port $PORST --bind 0.0.0.0 v2
worker: python manage.py runworker channel_layer --settings=django_project.settigns -v2
```

to

```
web: gunicorn django_project.wsgi
```

my application successfully built! Why would my procfile be resulting in that error?

Answer (score 0):

In model file Import the User

```
 from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
 User = get_user_model()
```

To

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

then use the User as Foreign key

Comment: thanks i'll try that! Then in settngs.py, should I set `AUTH_USER_MODEL='auth.User'`? Or should i not add that?

Comment: you no need to add AUTH_USER_MODEL='auth.User' in setting

Comment: I tried that but am now getting this error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'User'
`

Comment: I've been trying for days to figure this out. I will pay you $50 if you help me figure this out

Comment: do u have any remote software like teamviewer?

Comment: No but i have zoom if you want to get on a call? Do you have python experience and think you could figure this out? Also I have an important update which i posted in my Question, the Procfile may be the issue

Comment: Without using the debugger it's little bit difficult to find the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230352/discussion-between-usman-imtiaz-and-tom).