# Django: "AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet" when deploying to Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm consistently running into an error when deploying to production(**Heroku**), but the app works fine on my localhost. I see that many other people have this issue but none of the solutions work for me. One important note is that I do not call `django.setup()`, because when I do I get another error (`auth.User model not found`), but according to the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage) you should not have to call that when running the app on a web server (as I am). I've been really stuck on this so would appreciate any help anyone can give.

**The error is:**

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 136, in check_apps_ready
2021-03-26T10:33:44.756357+00:00 app[web.1]: raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
2021-03-26T10:33:44.756413+00:00 app[web.1]: django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I'm on Django 3.1.7, and looked at my requirements.txt and i believe my apps are up to date.

File structure: [image: image link]

Below is my code:

**Procfile**

```
release: python manage.py migrate
web: daphne django_project.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
worker: python manage.py runworker channels --settings=django_project.settings -v2
```

**blog/models.py**

```
print('~~~\n\nvery top in blog/models.py\n\n~~~')

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.urls import reverse
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

...

**settings.py**

```
# import django # should not need
import os
import django_heroku


print('~~~At top of settings~~~ ')
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = 'exhlfdat&vfum(-34*c2uroi(($ww(yo$9pv98=e6p^gl(-eoj' #todo: test removing this in own deployment

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']

# Application definition
# Allows Django to look for models (for Databases)
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'crispy_forms',
    'channels',
    'dal',
    'dal_select2',
    'storages',
    'blog',
    'chat',
    'users',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        #'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '')], #
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.asgi.application' # older version of django: 'django_project.routing.application'


DB_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
DATABASE_URL = DB_URL

DATABASES = { # Use this to use local test DB
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Password validation
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

DEBUG = 'True'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')],
        },
    },
}

django_heroku.settings(locals()) # maybe need maybe not

# CACHES = { # maybe need maybe not
#     "default": {
#          "BACKEND": "redis_cache.RedisCache",
#          "LOCATION": os.environ.get('REDIS_TLS_URL'),
#          "OPTIONS": {
#             "CONNECTION_POOL_KWARGS": {
#                 "ssl_cert_reqs": False
#             }
#         }
#     }
# }

DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = 4000


# django.setup() #todo maybe need #MAY NEED TO DO THIS, BUT WHEN I DO I GET "auth.User model not found" error
```

**asgi.py**

```
import os
import django
from channels.routing import get_default_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings')
django.setup()
application = get_default_application()
```

**~~~IMPORTANT UPDATE:~~~**

In my Procfile, I switched from using daphne to gunicorn just as a test, and the app built successfully! But now, I am getting this error below. It seems as though Django cannot load my 'django.contrib.auth' app for some reason. This is similar to another error i was having before: `ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'auth.User' that has not been installed`. Details on that error are [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66793874/django-auth-user-model-refers-to-model-auth-user-that-has-not-been-installed/66794318?noredirect=1#comment118072393_66794318).

[image]

I'm desperate at this point and considering destroying my database and then migrating but i'm not sure if that will cause problems or will even fix the issue. I don't have any valueable data at this point so maybe it's worth a shot?

Comment: Can you show your `django_project/asgi.py` file? Make sure to include the one used on heroku as I can see the one in your local copy of project is modified.

Comment: @GwynBleidD I just added my asgi.py file, that is what's currently pushed to heroku

Comment: Still struggling with this. It's fine gunicorn is used in the procfile, but breaks when daphne is used

Answer (score 4):

So there were 2 things that caused this problem in case anyone reads this in the future:

1. I copied and pasted a commonly used .gitignore file for python projects, and that included ignoring the db.sqlite3 file. Once I removed that from .gitignore this issue went away.
2. When i faced this issue after moving from gunicorn(wsgi) to daphne(asgi) I got this error again. All i had to do to fix was move the below code to the TOP of asgi.py:

- from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
- django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()